# What is the closest system to Star Wars Saga edition that's still in print?

Tags: game-recommendation, star-wars-saga-edition

I'm playing a game of Star Wars Saga Edition with friends, but I was horrified to find that due to ownership of names, and systems etc the book is no longer in print, and getting hold of a copy is next to impossible.

So I'd like to know how I can keep playing something very similar to this game once the campaign is over (the books don't belong to the GM, so I can't just borrow them).

I hear that Star wars Saga edition is part way between d20 Modern and 4E and replaced West End Games' d6 version. I'm sure there are other systems based on Star Wars as well. But which one is the closest fit, that I can still go out and buy somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing too much like Star Wars Saga Edition.  Luckily, getting a copy really shouldn't be that hard, they are at used bookstores in my area at least.

Are you looking for system or setting similarities?

**System**

SW:SE is a d20-based game.  It is not d20 Modern based, though depending on how close you want it, d20 Modern + d20 Future provides a somewhat similar play experience (more similar than using GURPS or Savage Worlds, I guess).

Wizards talked about both SW:SE and the 3.5e Tome of Battle as being 4e progenitors but I don't see a lot of similarity.  I liked both of those and played a good bit of ToB in 3.5e but hate 4e; perhaps it was "inspired by" them in a high level sense but there's not a lot of mechanical similarity.

**Setting**

The (much older) West End Games d6-based Star Wars had many, many books worth of support with setting, adventures, etc. It shares zero mechanics with SW:SE - it's a previously licensed game by a different company using a different system.  It is really good though, and the rules are free now as d6 Space Opera (without of course the Star Wars intellectual property).

There are the new Star Wars games by Fantasy Flight Games, which are of course set in the Star Wars universe, but are completely different than d20 system-wise.

**Kinda Both**

If you want it science fictioney, but d20ey, you could look at d20 Traveller.  It's a pretty bad d20 adaptation and not really a great intro to the Traveller universe, but depending on your values and personal initiative that may or may not be a deal killer.

Answer (score 3):

The closest games mechanics-wise would be d20 Modern + d20 Future, or Gamma World. Gamma World has quite a different setting, and some of the mutations would not even suit Star Wars aliens, and there would be no Jedi.

d20Modern +d20 Future could offer some of the Star Wars trappings - psionics and blasters, not so much the Jedi though. Fading Suns d20 would also provide a lot of the same sorts of mechanics. Traveller d20 psionics are quite different to Jedi Force powers, but would do in a pinch.

Failing all that, if you really want to play Saga Edition, try eBay or Noble Knight for second hand copies.

Comment: I would add that if you want to go with d20Modern/d20Future that you could use the psionics rules in the back of the Modern book, with some tweaks for flavor.  It seems a little much effort though when you could just buy the SWSE books second hand.