# How similar is Star Wars Saga to DnD 4th edition?

Tags: dnd-4e, star-wars-saga-edition

Before Dnd 4th ed came out, a lot of articles were printed saying that Star Wars: Saga Edition was like a "preview" of Dnd 4th ed. Now I find myself going the opposite direction: taking a group familiar with 4th ed through a brief tour of Saga. I'm not very familiar with Saga, however; how similar did they turn out to be mechanically?

Comment: Related (but definitely not duplicate): [What is the closest system to Star Wars Saga edition that's still in print?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12781/what-is-the-closest-system-to-star-wars-saga-edition-thats-still-in-print)

Comment: From [OpaCitiZen's answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/8076/321) to "What are the differences between Star Wars Revised Edition and Star Wars Saga Edition mechanically?", [this review of Saga Edition](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/13/13949.phtml) devotes a lot of text to comparisons with D&D 4e. (Someone more familiar than I with SW:SE and D&D 4e want to use that link as part of their answer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only played a session or two of each, but I'd say that no, SW Saga Edition does not particularly resemble D&D 4th Edition.  It's a streamlined version of 3rd, with standard/move/swift actions, easy multi-classing, and 3rd-ed style saving throws.  There are no powers (not like D&D 4 anyway), no healing surges, and no defined class roles.

It's quite a good system for the freewheeling cinematic style of Star Wars, IMHO.  I especially like the Reflex Defense mechanic, which unifies saving throws with AC.